# Uncaught TypeError when posting and receiving from iframe in modal/popup/lightbox

Tags: javascript, php, typeerror

On the  WordPress website I am working on, there is a popup on the front page (home) which contains an Vimeo iframe.

I have placed some Javascript in `header.php` to interact with the Vimeo player, that works like a charm wherever the Vimeo Player is embedded directly on the page/template/document.

However, on the homepage, where the iframe is embedded in a popup (Popup Builder Plugin), the JS is unable to communicate with the iframe, and it throws an error like this:

> *Uncaught TypeError: You must pass either a valid element or a valid id.
>       at new Player (player.js:2)*

What can I do so that the JS is able to post and receive from the iframe in the popup?

**The iframe:**

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?autoplay=1&muted=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

**Adding the Vimeo API JS in header.php:**

```
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

**The JS script (same results if I put it in the header, footer or directly on the front page template)**

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("fp-btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
     var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
     var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

     player.on('ended', function() {
        document.getElementById("clickTHIS").click();

     });

     player.getVideoTitle().then(function(title) {
     console.log('title:', title);
     });
   });

  </script>
```

The `EventListener` script does what it is supposed to which is to wait. But when I click the link to trigger the popup with the Vimeo iframe inside, it throws this error:

> *The player element passed isn’t a Vimeo embed. at new Player (player.js:2) at HTMLSpanElement. ((index):492)

Which is referring to this line: `var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);`

I've also tried changing the `querySelector` to `document.querySelector('iframe[href*="vimeo.com"]');` but then it just goes back to throwing the same error it did previously:

> *TypeError: You must pass either a valid element or a valid id. at new Player (player.js:2)*

As I've said, the code works anywhere else on the site, as long as the iframe is embedded directly on the page and not within a popup/lightbox or modal.

I am still lost here, so if anyone has had experience with this issue or has a clue of what's causing the problem, and how to fix it, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome. [This seems to work well](https://jsfiddle.net/43s598yn/) (look at the browser's console for the video title).

Comment: @Jeto Thank you. Yes this works, and that is the way I implement the script on the other pages where the iframe is embedded directly on the page/template. The problem is that I embed this iframe via a plugin. So that when users click the link, that triggers the popup with the iframe inside. Thats when i have problems and get these errors. Seems like the JS is unable to communicate with the plugin popup.

Comment: Are you sure the iframe is loaded with the proper URL when the vimeo player is instanciated? Can you `console.log(iframe.src)` right before calling the constructor?

Comment: @Jeto Okay, so by doing that, I get this error message: `Uncaught ReferenceError: iframe is not defined at <anonymous>:1:13`. In the popup builder dashboard, I have the option to `Insert Custom JS Variable` Im not sure what that means but if I click on it, It gives the option to type in a selector and attribute and then click insert. Could I use that in some way?

Comment: No idea because as I don't know about this popup builder thing. Is this a "traditional" popup (showing up in a distinct window on your browser)? Maybe try `var iframe = window.opener.document.querySelector('iframe');`.

Comment: @Jeto Yes this is a traditional popup. Click a button, a popup triggers with some content and an overlay over the rest of the page. Everything happens on the page that the visitor is on when clicking the button to trigger the popup. I'll try it now.

Comment: @Jeto When Implementing window.opener i get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null`. Thank you for taking the time to help me with this one, I've been struggling with this issue for days.

Comment: Oh, the iframe is within the popup? Please check the source of the popup itself (right click > view source) and paste it somewhere (such as pastebin.com)

Comment: @Jeto Yes, that is correct. I only get the iframe source when I view source once the popup window is open. Here it is: [link] (https://pastebin.com/CduJ9YJY) .Else I it only shows the entire page source that the popup is displaying on, do you want that?